# Grub2 keyboard layout when decrypting partition

Tags: opensuse, grub2, encryption, keyboard-layout

According to the [OpenSUSE 12.3 documentation](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/grub2.html) the only keyboard layout which can be used during a Grub2 boot is the "US keyboard layout".

Is there really no way to change the keyboard layout used when decrypting a partition during boot? If not, is this constraint due to Grub2 or OpenSUSE 12.3?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can provide a custom keyboard mapping to Grub2.
It's just that OpenSuSE seems not to provide the tools to do it.

Look at this wiki, it explains how to do:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:GRUB2#Custom_keyboard_layout

You have to get the `ckbcom` tool; it's a perl script, and you can get it from n other distribution if yours don't provide it.

Comment: I have followed the steps suggested by *drevo* on that page, though I modified the ckbcomp step to specify the `dvorak` variant of the `us` symbols file. Still no change to the password field on the GRUB2 boot loader, and only the standard QWERTY layout will let me decrypt my encrypted partitions.

Comment: @user1515834 I guess this is because the keyboard specification file is inside the encrypted disk and can't be accessed until you decrypt it. I know grub modules can be embedded in the MBR (or wherever grub has been installed), maybe there is a way to embed keyboard layout too in a similar way. If you manage to do it please post back the solution here

Comment: Or you can enter grub in rescue mode, and load the keyboard from there, then set the root, etc... and boot. You can also try (in case the characters you have introduced in your password are ASCII) to enter those characters with Alt+(ASCII char number in decimal).

Comment: Another possibility, if the only remaining problem is with typing the password, would be to just type it in qwerty. That is, a "key geography" password (much like the "passwords" on the smartphones). As what you type is not displayed on screen anyway. So when configuring grub on the running system, just switch temporarly to qwerty before typing the password; then you only need to type the same key sequences at boot.